# C - using different pipe ends in different processes

Tags: c, linux, pipe, system-calls, dup2

I've been searching and reading manuals, but still can't get the pipe mechanism. I'm making a program, which should do the following:

1. Parent process creates pipe, two child proccesses and waits.

   2. First child generates pairs of random numbers and passes them with space between to the second process via pipe. It goes on till
      gets signal from parent.
   3. Second child redirects it input so it is the output of the first child and redirects output to the out.txt file. Then it executes
      already compiled program, calculating GCD of numbers from (1);
2. Parent closes pipe and kills child.

So I got this C code (I reduced it so the post can fit the rules):

```
const int PIPE_READEND=0;
const int PIPE_WRITEEND=1;

        (...)
if (child1 == 0) {
        //Child1 code here
        close(fd[1]);

        struct sigaction sa;
        sa.sa_handler = sigHandler;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        if (sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL) == -1){ //Handling SIGUSR1 signal
            perror("Signal handling unexpected error");
            exit(errno);
        }
        int a,b;
        srand(time(&t));
        if (dup2(fd[PIPE_READEND],1) < 0){ //Redirecting stdout to the pipe fd.
            perror("In Child1 Redirecting stdout to pipe error");
            exit(errno);
        } 
        close(fd[0]);
        while(1){
            a = rand();
            b = rand();
            printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            sleep(1);
        }


       (...)
if ((child2 = fork()) < 0){
        perror("Fork error in Child2 process");
        exit(errno);
    } else if (child2 == 0){
        //Child2 code here
        close(fd[PIPE_READEND]);
        FILE *outfile = fopen("out.txt","w");
        dup2(fd[PIPE_WRITEEND],0); 
        dup2(outfile,1); 
        close(fd[PIPE_WRITEEND]);
        execl("c1/main","main",(char *)NULL);
```

The problem is, after executing it, out.txt stays empty. I'm disappointed about the pipe array indices, which one is used for what.

Comment: Like we don't have the code of your other program. We can't help you more. You have a lot of strange code. For example, you replace 1 by pipe[0]. This is useless because write on the exit of a pipe don't work. I don't understand why you want use signal.

Comment: You need to read from the read end and write into the write end. You are reading from the write end and writing to the read end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write and read from wrong indexes of pipe. You need to change them:

This redirects stdout to pipe input.

```
   close(fd[0]);
   dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
```

This redirects pipe output to stdin.

```
   close(fd[1]);
   dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
```

Also `dup2` takes integer, not pointer, so you should do:

```
   f = fopen("out.txt", "w");
   dup2(fileno(f), STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    FILE *outfile = fopen("out.txt","w");
    dup2(fd[PIPE_WRITEEND],0); 
    dup2(outfile,1);
```

This makes no sense. The `dup2` function doesn't take a `FILE *` as a parameter. Use `open`, not `fopen`.

Comment: @Stargateur Emm, thanks, still empty though. However, I noticed a thing. The program, that executes in `execl()` command prompts "DONE" to stdout, when done. My program prompts "TERMINATED",when done. And "DONE" appears before "TERMINATED", so `execl()` somehow doesn't wait for the major program and its numbers. Can't see the way fixing though.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for advice. I've changed it a little bit, but still get the same issue. int fdOut = open("out.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH); dup2(fdOut,1); //Redirecting output to "out.txt" close(fd[PIPE_WRITEEND]); execl("c1/main","main",(char *)NULL); Observe any idea where the bug can be?